# Oracle DB insert and do nothing on duplicate key

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to insert some data in oracle DB, without previously checking if it already exist.

Does exist any way, transiction on oracle to catch the exception inside the query and handle it to don't return any exception?

It would be perfect something in mysql's style like

```
insert .... on duplicate key a=a
```

Comment: Which Oracle version? 11.2 introduced a hint for this.

Comment: which hint has introduced?

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm). The syntax is a bit different from a regular insert though;

```
MERGE INTO test USING (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Test#1' AS value FROM DUAL    -- your row to insert here
) t ON (test.id = t.id)                          -- duplicate check
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (id, value) VALUES (t.id, t.value);    -- insert if no duplicate
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35b50/1).

Answer (score 4):

If you can use PL/SQL, and you have a unique index on the columns where you don't want any duplicates, then you can catch the exception and ignore it:

```
begin
   insert into your_table (your_col) values (your_value);
exception
   when dup_val_on_index then null;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since 11g there is the `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint that ignores Unique Constraint-exceptions and let the script go on with the next row if there is any, see [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG). The exception is not logged. It needs two arguments, the table name and the index name.

```
INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(my_table, my_table_idx) */
INTO my_table(id,name,phone)
    VALUES (24,'Joe','+49 19450704');
```