# My query generates an ORA-00933 error, why is that?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm using php to generate an oracle query like this:

```
...

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO $table_name %s %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ", 
            $this->prepare_insert_sql("", $fields, false), 
            $this->prepare_insert_sql(" VALUES ", $values, true));
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($fields); $index++) {
        if ($index > 0) {
            $sql .= ", ";
        }
        $sql .= $fields[$index] . "='" . $values[$index] . "'";
    }
...
```

And the result query is:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_CONFIG(KEY,VALUE) 
VALUES ('1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1','822') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE KEY='1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1', VALUE='822'
```

It gives an ORA-00933 error.

I really can't seem to find the error. Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: `key`, far as I know is a reserved word in MySQL. Whether it's the same for Oracle, that I'd have to Google. It would need to be wrapped in backticks.

Comment: It's confirmed, `key` is an Oracle reserved keyword also. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm - Either give it another name, or wrap it in backticks `\``

Comment: Still got the same error. Seems like oracle doesn't have `on duplicate ` condition

Comment: That I couldn't help you out with. I don't know Oracle. Try and wrap the `%s %s` with quotes.

Comment: It does have one http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: MySQL is bought by Oracle :) Look at the link it's for mysql 5.0

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17254072/ - Use  `MERGE` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17946783/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `merge` instead of `insert into` worked.

```
MERGE INTO TBL_CONFIG USING DUAL ON (KEY ='1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1')
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET VALUE = '822'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (KEY, VALUE) VALUES ('1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1', '822')
```

Comment: Right on, glad to hear it.

Comment: I appriciate all the help

Answer (score 1):

Per your posted code `KEY` is a reserve word and so you need to escape it using `""` double quote like below

```
INSERT INTO TBL_CONFIG("KEY",VALUE) 
VALUES ('1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1','822') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE "KEY"='1_default_meter_type_for_device_type_1', VALUE='822'
```

**EDIT:**

Totally confused. Oracle doesn't have `ON Dulicate Key Update`. You have to use `MERGE` statement as commented by Fred-ii.

Comment: So it's quotes and not backticks then. Yet, that would need to be done in OP's query. `$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO $table_name %s %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ",...` - What the OP shown us in the 2nd part, is what the query's results are.

Comment: Still, I get same error. I belive it's `on duplicate key` part

Comment: @Fred-ii-, It's Oracle and so you need to use `"` to escape reserve word.

Comment: OP needs to use `MERGE` http://stackoverflow.com/a/17946783/ - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17254072/ *"Oracle doesn't have on duplicate key update"*

Comment: That I couldn't say for sure. I don't know Oracle, but I do know "Google" ;-)

Comment: `on duplicate key` is a no go on oracle unlike mysql

Comment: *"as commented by others"* - lol as found by Fred ;-) I'm just kidding.

Comment: Thank for the mention Rahul :) *Cheers* Glad we were able to help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO $table_name %s %s ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ",
    $this->prepare_insert_sql("", $fields, false),
    $this->prepare_insert_sql(" VALUES ", $values, true)
);

for($index = 0; $index < count($fields); $index++) {
    if($index > 0) {
        $sql .= ", ";
    }

    // added " before and after field name
    $sql .= '"' . $fields[$index] . '"=\'' . $values[$index] . "'";
}
```